# Scoped Style Sheets without HTML5

Tags: css, html

I am needing an approach where I can scope CSS files to a certain portion of the page. In theory, this example should do what I need:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <style scope>
            @import url("style1.css");
        </style>
        <div class="testText">Test with Style 1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <style scope>
            @import url("style2.css");
        </style>
        <div class="testText">Test with Style 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I found out that the scope element is only available in some browsers right now (Firefox 21+ mainly). So, I'm looking for a lazy way out or a problem. I need to integrate some content with different styles into a site. We tried loading both css filesets, but there are some style names that appear in both stylesheets, so it will be a lot of work to rename the style names in one fileset and in the corresponding html content, specially because you cannot just refactor with Eclipse... :)

Is there any other solution that can render such a result that is widely compatible?

Regards

Comment: Chrome does support scoped styles, too

Comment: @gustavohenke Not by default, so one can assume that it's not available to Chrome.

Comment: Rob W is right, on Chrome you need to enable experimental mode. What I'm looking for is for an alternative that will work with IE8+ and Firefox 17+... If it means using some css framework or other tricks, it's fine, just want to see if there's some other way...

Comment: @Martin Based on your replies to the current answer, I recommend to take a look at [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). The [nested rules feature](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules) is an appealing solution to your problem. Since LESS is just a superset of CSS, learning/using it will be very easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scoped styles aren't well-supported at this point and are going to cause you problems if you're expecting any sort of cross-browser coverage.

The only way you can really achieve what you're after is to use a unique classname (or ID) for each 'section' and then use inheritance to sort-of namespace your CSS.  So if you want to target one specific section of the page, give it's parents a classname (eg: `class="testone"`) and then make sure that any styles you want to apply to that section are appended with that classname:

```
.testone .title{...}
.testone h1{...}
.testone a{...
```

etc.

Failing that, there is also a [jQuery-based scope polyfill](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin) which should give you a more browser-independent way of working with scoped CSS.  It isn't something I've worked with so don't have any experience to offer, but it looks very promising from the few moments I've spent with it!

Do remember that as with any JavaScript-based solution like this one, anyone who loads your page without JavaScript enabled isn't going to get those little extra niceties so it's important to ensure that the page still behaves in an acceptable manner even when JS is disabled.

Comment: OK, tried the approach and it works, will add it to your response. However, this means I need to rename the styles in all css files I already have, the HTML replacement is easier as it can be inherited... Is there a way to make te inherited styles backwards compatible with non-touched html files?

Comment: Hi Martin,  it really does depend on how your site is set up.  You should not need to edit huge swaths of your CSS.  You would normally have a set of 'base' CSS styles - which would apply throughout the site, and then use the declarations I've suggested above as an overwrite to make the styles more specific for certain positions/situations.  Otherwise, there's also a polyfill available, although I've not done anything with it so have no experience.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Wow, the jQuery based polyfill seems just like what we need... Will try it out and see if it works. After all, new pages will only use new styles, and we want to get rid of old styles eventually, it's just the need of keeping stuff separated with a low cost...

Comment: Glad to hear that's answered your question.  If you do need any further help, feel free to do a search here on Stack Overflow and, failing that, open up a new question!  If your current question has been answered, please do remember to mark it (green check against the relevant answer).  This will ensure that anyone else search for a similar solution in the future will be able to find the answer as easily as possible.

Comment: Wow, 5 YEARS later, and this is still the only way to get this to work. Sad but true...

Answer (score 2):

The attribute name in HTML5 drafts is `scoped`, not `scope`.

Support to it is slowly being implemented, but there is little reason to use the attribute, or scoped style sheets. Most browsers will take `<style scoped>` simply as `<style>` and apply it to the entire document.

Thus, it is best to analyze the problem you are trying to solve and find a different approach to it. In many cases, it is trivial, using suitable contextual selectors. Assign an `id` attribute to an element and use an id selector as the first component of selectors.

Comment: Not anymore. Nearly every browser has dropped support for it.

Comment: Indeed, but I seem to remember that a replacement is in the works.  I can't remember what it is called though.