# style "scoped" <style scoped> attribute not supported in chrome 36+. Any alternative or substitute for that?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using scoped attribute in style tag. 
It is not supported by chrome browser.
Any alternative or substitute to achieving this functionality that work with chrome browser.

Comment: Please provide sample code - see here [mcve]

Comment: It is not supported in any of browser except mozilla firefox

Comment: Any alternative solution?

Comment: Why you need it so bad even it is not supported

Comment: I know it is not supported @Mandeep and want the alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can really achieve what you're after is to use a unique classname (or ID) for each 'section' and then use inheritance to sort-of namespace your CSS. So if you want to target one specific section of the page, give it's parents a classname (eg: class="testone") and then make sure that any styles you want to apply to that section are appended with that classname:

```
.testone .title{...}
.testone h1{...}
.testone a{...
```

etc.

Failing that, there is also a jQuery-based scope polyfill which should give you a more browser-independent way of working with scoped CSS. It isn't something I've worked with so don't have any experience to offer, but it looks very promising from the few moments I've spent with it!

Do remember that as with any JavaScript-based solution like this one, anyone who loads your page without JavaScript enabled isn't going to get those little extra niceties so it's important to ensure that the page still behaves in an acceptable manner even when JS is disabled.

**Source** : [Scoped Style Sheets without HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899697/scoped-style-sheets-without-html5)